# Can't access static files with a URL-encoding characters in the names

Tags: php, get, url-encoding

On my CDN, I have some old files with names that were created using [rawurlencode](http://hp.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) function. E.g. one of the files has this name:

**Cat%20presentation.pdf**

Now, when I try to read this file, I get a "File not found" error:

```
GET cdn.example.com/documents/Cat%20presentation.pdf
```

I believe that's because of the encoded space character in the name - `%20`. For the browser (and the CDN) what I'm asking for is this:

**Cat presentation.pdf**

while the "%20" part is actually in the filename.

Is there any way I can get around this and access the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to URL-encode the "%" character into "%25":

```
GET cdn.example.com/documents/Cat%2520presentation.pdf
```

But if I were you I'd just fix their filenames instead.